# Unable to debug ArcGIS 10.2 add-in on ArcMap with "No GUI components found in this Add-In"

Tags: arcobjects, add-in, visual-studio

I am working on an ArcGIS add-in (a very simple toolbar with a few buttons) with VB.Net and ArcObjects SDK in Visual Studio 2010. The solution was built successfully and the debug settings were configured.

When I hit Debug, ArcMap application was opened. I couldn't find the toolbar docked anywhere on the ArcMap toolbar. I went to "Customize" -> "Add-in Manager" and the add-in being debugged was not there. Then I tried "Add From File...", located the "esriaddin" file and clicked "Install Add-in". It populated a message box saying "No GUI components found in this Add-In."

I made some Google searches but haven't got any luck to reach a solution yet.

What was I missing? Has anyone come across the same issue and any direction?

Thanks in advance!

------ EDIT ------ the esriaddinx file attached as below

```xml
<ESRI.Configuration xmlns="http://schemas.esri.com/Desktop/AddIns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>CFAArc10ToolsAddIn</Name>
  <AddInID>{112b1e91-3b7f-4d18-8584-65427e99b287}</AddInID>
  <Description>Contains Custom Tools for use in Arc10</Description>
  <Version>4.0</Version>
  <Image>Images\CFAArc10ToolsAddIn.png</Image>
  <Author>{First Last names}</Author>
  <Company>{Company name}</Company>
  <Date>30/05/2014</Date>
  <Targets>
    <Target name="Desktop" version="10.2" />
  </Targets>
  <AddIn language="CLR" library="CFAArc10ToolsAddIn.dll" namespace="CFAArc10ToolsAddIn">
    <ArcMap>
      <Commands>
        <Button>
          ... ...
        </Button>
        ... ...
      </Commands>
      <Toolbars>
        <Toolbar>
          ... ...
        </Toolbar>
        ... ...
      </Toolbars>
    </ArcMap>
  </AddIn>
</ESRI.Configuration>
```

Comment: The problem most likely is in the config.esriaddinx file, can you open that in notepad and paste the XML into the question (mask any personal data contained in it)

Comment: You've taken out too much. The part that's really interesting is the bit between <Button> and </Button>, in particular category="something" and onDemand="false". Just to confirm, the tool inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button. If you have created this using the dialog then it should be right, unless you've modified that line.

Comment: A further question.. are you on a 64 bit OS? if so have you built the addin for x86? if you leave it as the default *any CPU* you will have this problem.

Comment: Yes, I have "category" in the file but they all look good. I don't have "onDemand=false" in the file at all. The file was created automatically.

Comment: That may be a 10.1 thing, I'm comparing it to one of my own. What about the 64bit issue?

Comment: I am with a Win XP SP 3 computer. It's 32-bit OS. "Any CPU" is left as default.

Comment: You seem to have done everything right. You have a public sub new() and have overridden OnClick() and OnUpdate() in the button... can you install add-ins at all? try downloading an add-in and installing it. It could be a 10.2 Windows XP registry problem.

Comment: Yes, I can install add-ins. By the way, I got it sorted. As there was already an Add-in (a shared Add-in) with the same name as the one I am debugging there could be naming conflict in Add-in Manager. I didn't realise that could have been the issue. Now that I manually removed the shared one the one I am debugging is now working! Thanks so much Michael for your help.

Comment: Oh cool. You're welcome, not that I helped much.